# rake db:migrate refinerycms get error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, refinerycms, mysql2

I have refinerycms 2.1.5 and running with sqlite3 all DDBB and works fine.
Now i want migrate my app to Mysql, then I change into proyect:
config/database.yml:

```
development: &development
  adapter: mysql2
  host: 127.0.0.1
  username: root
  password: root
  database: refinerycms_develop
  port: 3306

test: &test
  adapter: mysql2
  host: 127.0.0.1
  username: root
  password: root
  database: refinerycms_test
  port: 3306
```

Into Gemfile :

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'mysql2'
  gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter'
end
```

This is my gem list:

```
actionmailer (4.2.4, 4.2.3, 4.1.8, 3.2.22)
actionpack (4.2.4, 4.2.3, 4.1.8, 3.2.22)
actionview (4.2.4, 4.2.3, 4.1.8)
activejob (4.2.4, 4.2.3)
activemodel (4.2.4, 4.2.3, 4.1.8, 3.2.22)
activerecord (4.2.4, 4.2.3, 4.1.8, 3.2.22)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.3.18)
activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (1.3.18)
activerecord-mysql-adapter (0.0.1)
activerecord-mysql2-adapter (0.0.3)
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.1.0)
activeresource (3.2.22)
activesupport (4.2.4, 4.2.3, 4.1.8, 3.2.22)
acts_as_indexed (0.8.3)
addressable (2.3.8)
arel (6.0.3, 5.0.1.20140414130214, 3.0.3)
awesome_nested_set (3.0.2, 2.1.6)
babosa (1.0.2)
bcrypt (3.1.10 x86-mingw32)
bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5 x86-mingw32)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
builder (3.2.2, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.10.6, 1.7.7)
byebug (6.0.2)
capybara (2.4.4)
cliver (0.3.2)
coffee-rails (4.1.0, 3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.4.1, 2.3.0)
coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1, 1.8.0)
coveralls (0.8.2)
database_cleaner (1.3.0)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
decorators (2.0.1, 1.0.5)
devise (3.5.2, 2.2.8)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
docile (1.1.5)
domain_name (0.5.24)
dragonfly (1.0.11, 0.9.15)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.6.0, 2.2.2)
factory_girl (4.4.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.4.1)
ffi (1.9.10 x86-mingw32)
friendly_id (5.1.0, 4.0.10.1)
generator_spec (0.9.3)
globalid (0.3.6)
globalize (5.0.1, 3.1.0)
hike (1.2.3)
http-cookie (1.0.2)
i18n (0.7.0, 0.6.11)
io-console (0.4.2)
jbuilder (2.3.1)
jdbc-mysql (5.1.36)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (4.0.5, 3.1.2, 2.3.0)
jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
json (1.8.3, 1.7.7)
launchy (2.4.3)
loofah (2.0.3)
mail (2.6.3, 2.5.4)
mime-types (2.6.2, 2.4.3, 1.25.1)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.8.0, 5.4.3, 4.3.2)
multi_json (1.11.2, 1.10.1)
mysql (2.9.1 x86-mingw32)
mysql2 (0.4.1 x86-mingw32, 0.4.0 x86-mingw32, 0.3.20 x86-mingw32)
netrc (0.10.3)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2 x86-mingw32)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
pg (0.17.1 x86-mingw32)
polyglot (0.3.5)
psych (2.0.0)
quiet_assets (1.1.0)
rack (1.6.4, 1.5.2, 1.4.7)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.4)
rack-test (0.6.3, 0.6.2)
rails (4.2.4, 4.2.3, 4.1.8, 3.2.22)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
rails-i18n (4.0.5, 0.7.4)
railties (4.2.4, 4.2.3, 4.1.8, 3.2.22)
rake (10.4.2, 0.9.6)
rb-readline (0.5.1)
rdoc (4.2.0, 4.0.0, 3.12.2)
refinerycms (2.1.5)
refinerycms-acts-as-indexed (2.0.1, 1.0.0)
refinerycms-authentication (2.1.5)
refinerycms-authentication-devise (1.0.4)
refinerycms-core (2.1.5)
refinerycms-dashboard (2.1.5)
refinerycms-i18n (3.0.1, 2.1.0)
refinerycms-images (2.1.5)
refinerycms-page-images (2.1.1, 1.0.4)
refinerycms-page-resources (0.0.1)
refinerycms-pages (2.1.5)
refinerycms-resources (2.1.5)
refinerycms-wymeditor (1.0.6)
responders (2.1.0)
rest-client (2.0.0.rc2 x86-mingw32, 1.8.0 x86-mingw32)
routing-filter (0.5.1, 0.3.1)
rspec-core (3.3.2)
rspec-expectations (3.3.1)
rspec-mocks (3.3.2)
rspec-rails (3.3.3)
rspec-retry (0.4.4)
rspec-support (3.3.0)
rubygems-update (2.4.8)
rubyzip (1.1.6)
sass (3.4.18, 3.2.19)
sass-rails (5.0.4, 4.0.5, 3.2.6)
sdoc (0.4.1)
seo_meta (2.0.0.rc.1, 1.4.0)
simplecov (0.10.0)
simplecov-html (0.10.0)
speakingurl-rails (1.1.5)
spring (1.4.0)
spring-commands-rspec (1.0.4)
sprockets (3.3.4, 2.12.3, 2.2.3)
sprockets-rails (2.3.3, 2.2.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.10 x86-mingw32)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
term-ansicolor (1.3.2)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5, 0.3.4)
tilt (2.0.1, 1.4.1)
tins (1.6.0)
tiny_tds (0.6.2 x86-mingw32)
treetop (1.4.15)
truncate_html (0.9.3)
turbolinks (2.5.3)
tzinfo (1.2.2, 0.3.44)
tzinfo-data (1.2015.6)
uglifier (2.7.2)
unf (0.1.4)
unf_ext (0.0.7.1 x86-mingw32)
warden (1.2.3)
web-console (2.2.1)
websocket-driver (0.6.2)
websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
will_paginate (3.0.7)
xpath (2.0.0)
yaml_db (0.3.0)
zilch-authorisation (0.0.1)
```

I get this error

```
 rake aborted!
 NoMethodError: undefined method 'accept' for nil:NilClass
 Task: TOP => db:migrate
```

stack-traces:

```
 DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (fist_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method 'accept' for nil:NilClass
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in 'to_sql' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:38:in 'select_values' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:587:in 'get_all_versions' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:745:in 'migrated' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:668:in 'current_version'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:685:in 'block in migrate' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:685:in 'each' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:685:in 'detect' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:685:in 'migrate' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in 'up' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in 'migrate' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:193:in 'block (2 levels> in >' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in 'call' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in 'block in execute' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in 'each' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in 'execute' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in 'block in invoke_with_call_chain' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in 'mon_synchronize' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in 'invoke_with_call_chain' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in 'invoke' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in 'invoke_task' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in 'block (2 levels) in top_level' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in 'each' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in 'block in top_level' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in 'run_with_threads' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in 'top_level' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in 'block in run' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in 'standard_exception_handling' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in 'run' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in '' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in 'load' 
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in '' 
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: please post stack-traces in plain-text so searching for it is possible

Answer (score -1):

Run the following:

1. gem update --system
2. rake db:create

Let me know if that works ?

Comment: I try this and does not work , then i prefer migrate to PostgreSQL